# Combining a random quote generator with typewriter effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I've been playing around with a project that includes a random quote generator, and I was hoping to combine it with a simple typewriter-esque animation when the generator loads a new quote.

Problem is I know very little about javascript and basically have no idea what I'm doing, which makes it hard to implement other people's similar-but-not-quite-it solutions.

The basics of the code is this;

```js
const generateQuote = function() {
  const quotes = [{
      quote: "Here's a text",
    },
    {
      quote: "Here's another one",
    },
    {
      quote: "Lorem ipsum bla bla",
    },
    {
      quote: "I can do this all day",
    }
  ];

  let arrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  document.getElementById("quotetxt").innerHTML = quotes[arrayIndex].quote;
}

window.onload = function loadquote() {
  generateQuote();
  document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener('click', generateQuote);
}
```

```html
<p id="quotetxt"> </p>
<button id="generate">generate</button>
```

I've tried combining it with scripts for typewriter effects I've seen around (like the basic one on W3schools), but I can't figure out how to make it work like I want. I can make the initially loaded quote appear with the animation, or animate single texts, but not from a random array on button press like I want.

At one point I managed to somehow make the quote generator scramble all the letters in the quotes, though I have no idea how I did that and I didn't keep the code.

I've seen some jquery stuff around for typewriter effects, but they all seem far more advanced than what I'm looking for, but if there's a simple one you could recommend that would be fine too.

(I'm also completely new to stackoverflow, I did my best to follow the guidelines but I apologise if I missed something)

Comment: Your question is OK - there will be some ppl who will vote it down or close it due to the missing example of a typewriter. If you have a working but too complex function you wnt to simplify, then the question belongs at codereview more than here, where we expect a [mcve] with something that does not work you need help to fix. Here you basically just ask for someone to add missing code and that is frowned upon. I still answered it though, because I wanted to see how simple I could make it.

Comment: "*I apologise if I missed something*" - as above, nothing wrong with the question.  Personally I might have closed it as a duplicate as your quote generator works fine so you're asking how to do a typewriter effect, for which there are [many existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+typewriter) including one with just [css only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887298/multiline-typewriter-effect-with-two-consistent-words/57887588#57887588).  The deciding factor is that you're not asking how to do a typewriter, but how to "*combine one with your code*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest I could think of

Note I have changed some of the code layout. For example there is no need to create the quote array every time the generateQuote is called.
I also clear the existing quote if the button is clicked mid quote.
I put the typewriter function inside the load event handler since it needs the textElement to be in scope. I could get the textElement each time inside the function if I wanted to move the function outside the load event handler, but this is a simple script so I stayed pragmatic.

```js
const quotes = [
  { quote: "Here's a text" },
  { quote: "Here's another one" },
  { quote: "Lorem ipsum bla bla" },
  { quote: "I can do this all day" }
];


const generateQuote = () => {
  let arrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  return quotes[arrayIndex].quote;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textElement = document.getElementById('quotetxt');
  let tId; // timeout handle
  // Typewriter function
  const typeWriter = (text, i = 0) => {
    if (i < text.length) { // while the counter is less than the length of the string
      textElement.innerHTML = text.substring(0, i + 1); // show next letter
      // call the function with the counter at the next letter
      tId = setTimeout(() => typeWriter(text, i + 1), 100); // Adjust speed by changing timeout
    }
  };

  // Event listener for button
  document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    clearTimeout(tId); // kill running typewriting
    textElement.textContent = "";
    typeWriter(generateQuote());
  });
  typeWriter(generateQuote()); // initialise
});
```

```html
<p id="quotetxt"> </p>
<button id="generate">generate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/blackfrom80s/pen/ogoxLw)

Added to include the typewriter effect, you will have to reset the `innerHTML` (as this does) in order to get the effect again when pressing the button.

```js
const generateQuote = function() {
  const quotes = [{
      quote: "Here's a text",
    },
    {
      quote: "Here's another one",
    },
    {
      quote: "Lorem ipsum bla bla",
    },
    {
      quote: "I can do this all day",
    }
  ];

  let arrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  document.getElementById("quotetxt").innerHTML = `<p  class="line-1 anim-typewriter">${quotes[arrayIndex].quote}</p>`;
}

window.onload = function loadquote() {
  generateQuote();
  document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener('click', generateQuote);
}
```

```css
/* Google Fonts */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);

/* Global */

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  padding: 4em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

.line-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 180%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 24em;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="quotetxt"></div>
<button id="generate">generate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a constantly running function that removes the first char from the text and types it. On the button click, empty the output and assign the new text. That's it.

```js
let text = ''

function type() {
  if (text) {
    document.querySelector('#show').textContent += text[0]
    text = text.slice(1)
  }
}

setInterval(type, 50)

function buttonClick() {
  document.querySelector('#show').textContent = ''
  text = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]
}

//


let quotes = [
  'Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex.',
  'Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.',
  'Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.',
  'Two driven jocks help fax my big quiz.',
  'Five quacking zephyrs jolt my wax bed.',
  'The five boxing wizards jump quickly.',
  'Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.',
  'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.',
  'Jinxed wizards pluck ivy from the big quilt.',
  'Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels.',
  'We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize.',
  'A mad boxer shot a quick, gloved jab to the jaw of his dizzy opponent.',
  'Jaded zombies acted quaintly but kept driving their oxen forward.',
  'The job requires extra pluck and zeal from every young wage earner.',
]
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClick()">go</button>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I add simple code below.

```js
    var timeId;
const generateQuote = function () {
  const quotes = [
    {
      quote: "Here's a text",
    },
    {
      quote: "Here's another one",
    },
    {
      quote: "Lorem ipsum bla bla",
    },
    {
      quote: "I can do this all day",
    },
  ];

  let arrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  var i = 0;
  var txt = quotes[arrayIndex].quote; /* The text */
  var speed = 100; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */
  clearInterval(timeId);
  document.getElementById("quotetxt").innerHTML = "";
  function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      document.getElementById("quotetxt").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
      timeId = setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  }
  typeWriter();
};

window.onload = function loadquote() {
  generateQuote();
  document
    .getElementById("generate")
    .addEventListener("click", generateQuote);
};
```

```html
 <p id="quotetxt"></p>
    <button id="generate">generate</button>
```

Comment: It breaks when you hit the button again when still generating